# Convert comma separated data to numeric values

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame and want to convert part of it to numeric values like that:

```
> df$TotalReturn : 
str
 chr [1:3036] "182,83" "182,83" "186,4" "190,57" "191,17" 
              "193,25" "190,57" "184,02" "181,34" "172,11" 
              "169,73" "160,2" "175,09" "172,11" "170,92" 
              "176,58" "171,51" "170,92" "173,9" "168,54" 
              "167,34" "166,75" "166,45" "167,34" "164,37" "159,01" 
              "158,11" "154,84" "156,63" etc.
```

to convert it I use:

```
totalReturns <- (as.double(gsub(",",".",df$TotalReturn)))
```

However my data looks like that:

```
> totalReturns
str
 num [1:3036] 183 183 186 191 191 ...
```

Why is R rounding? How to get the full numeric/double value?

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: if I set `options(digits=0)` I get the same results as you. But the digits are there they are just not printed to the console. Maybe check the `options("digits")` settings.

Answer (score 4):

It's only rounded for displaying with `str`:

```
str(as.double(gsub(",",".","182,83")))
#num 183
```

The vector is double precision:

```
as.double(gsub(",",".","182,83"))
#[1] 182.83
```

Note that you can specify the decimal separator when reading from a file (e.g., using `read.table`).

Comment: Thx for your answer! What do you mean by `specify the decimal separator when reading from a file `? I am using `sep = ";"`.

Comment: I pointed out this out (using `dec=","` with `scan()`) in my [answer to a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859606/convert-from-string-to-double-nas-introduced-by-coercion/20859730#20859730) just the other day. (Is the OP the same as [user1000](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2847689/user1000)?